# C# Random Number Creation

Tags: c#

Ok so I know to generate a random number one would create a method such as this:

```
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Now lets say instead of having it take two numbers example:

```
RandomNumber(4, 25);
```

I want it to make the max a value that will be determined, example:

```
RandomNumber(0, Alist.Count);
```

Is there any way to do this? I tried making AList.Count = another int number and putting that in but to no avail.

Comment: That's not really how the random number generator is supposed to be used.  What are you trying to generate these numbers for?

Comment: To randomly select a number from a list, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you might want to create the `Random` instance outside of the method, perhaps hold an instance in a static field. See what happens when you call your method with the same values repeatedly in quick succession. How random does your random number need to be? There are better pseudo-random number generators available if you need *more* randomness

Comment: I want the max value to be determined by the size of a list that will be decided when i run the program.

Comment: How's that different to what you've got? `RandomNumber(0, Alist.Count)` will return a random number greater or equal to 0 and less than the current size of `Alist`.

Comment: It kept giving me an error on that line, I just thought that was the cause.

Comment: What is the error you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `RandomNumber(0, Alist.Count)` will work perfectly. However, instead of making a function for that, you should be using *one* instance of `Random`:

```
Random r = new Random();
DoSomething(r.Next(0, Alist.Count));
DoSomething(r.Next(0, Alist.Count));
DoSomething(r.Next(0, Alist.Count));
// etc., whatever you want.
```

Edit: So you want a random element from a list?

```
Random r = new Random();
Alist[r.Next(0, Alist.Count)] // There's your random element.
```

Comment: What if I also want to make sure each random number generated is unique?

Comment: @Emerica.: There are several ways to do this. One of the easiest (if you don't need the list again) is to do `Alist.Sort(x => r.Next());` and you've got a randomized list; now just read the top off of it, then remove the top. Do that as many times as you need.

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a list and storing the numbers in it using a while loop to ensure the new created value is not located in the list. Then I used the list for its purpose, clear it and reuse the same process. IS this a bad method?

Comment: @Emerica. @minitech As a bit of a purist, I -really- don't like seeing `do { generate_random_number } while (!random_number_is_unique)` loops. It's the time complexity that primarily concerns me. Sure, it's fine for tiny lists - but medium lists it's getting a bit slow (1000 elements ~= 33ms on my computer) and for huge lists it's virtually stalled (100k elements takes over **4 minutes**). Compare that to a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which would take just 10ms or so to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Mania: Yes, okay, but if it works, no need to add extra complexity - the OP doesn't appear to be ready for anything too terribly advanced. If it needed a speed improvement, I'd use what I suggested earlier - using `.Sort()`.

Comment: @minitech: I saw that, but assuming `Alist` is a `List<>` it does not compile? `Sort` expects a `Comparison<T>` taking two parameters and returning an int representing the comparison. And `(x, y) => r.Next(-1, 2)` would be a bit of an abuse seeing as `List<>.Sort(Comparison<>)` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) as being able to throw an `ArgumentException` if the result of the comparison function is inconsistent. In practice I don't believe it does, but this may not hold true for all versions of the .NET framework. (sorry, not intending to nitpick)

Comment: @Mania: Sorry, it would be `(x, y) => r.Next()`. And although it's documented as doing that, I doubt it will be an issue in this case. If the alternative is less clarity, strict compliance doesn't matter that much... kind of like `innerHTML`. (Well, that's JavaScript `;)`)

Comment: @minitech: Out of curiousity I gave it a quick test, whilst `List<>.Sort((x, y) => r.Next(-1, 2))` did not throw for my few test cases, `List<>.Sort((x, y) => -1)` throws immediately. So sorting with a random comparison would be a timebomb waiting to go off... I would not recommend using it ;).

Comment: @Mania: You've discovered something *very* interesting. I tested with [this code](http://codepad.org/jNHXnN65), and after 1,000,000 iterations, there isn't a problem. However, when permanently returning `-1`, it evaluates the same pair several times (almost as if checking if it's random... hmm...), and changes orders, then throws an `ArgumentException`... try it, it's really strange.

Comment: @minitech: The `ArraySortHelper<>` in reflector makes for interesting reading - `IndexOutOfRange` is caught and rethrown as a `ArgumentException`, with the ResourceString `"Arg_BogusIComparer"` (love the name). Looking deeper, you can see the sort keeps on searching upwards until it finds an element equal or greater. With a `-1` comparer that will obviously never terminate, and a `Random` comparer cannot guarantee that it will before the end of the array is reached...

Comment: ... the reason the test code (nice btw) does not break on Randoms? `List<>` has a heap of extra capacity in the array giving `Random` ample additional chances to return with the opposite sign. Try it again with the `List<>` being sized exactly for its count, and it'll throw a lot more often.

Comment: @Emerica, with randomization you cannot guarantee that each number is unique (statistically speaking). If you want a random order and guarantee that a item in the list is used only once, delete the item from the list after getting it..

Answer (score 1):

In light of the comments in minitech's answer I thought I'd give my own spin on returning random indexes from a list - feel free to take it or leave it ;).

Personally I'd declare an extension method for O(n) shuffling a list (using a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)):

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> list, Random random)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (random == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("random");
        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(0, i + 1);
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
        return list; // best made a void method, but for examples I'll return list.
    }
}
```

And then if reordering the original list is acceptable, simply call:

```
Alist.Shuffle(new Random());
```

If reordering is not acceptable, and I want a random list of unique indexes I'd use:

```
List<int> indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, Alist.Count).ToList().Shuffle(new Random());
```

Or I could create a new list, with the original elements shuffled:

```
var shuffledList = Alist.ToList().Shuffle(new Random());
```

It's a pretty versatile extension method, perhaps worth adding to one's arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not create a method like that. Consider:

```
int num1 = RandomNumber(1, 6);
int num2 = RandomNumber(1, 6);
```

Almost all of the times, the two variables will end up having the same value. If you create `Random` instances too close in time, they will get the seed from the same clock tick, and end up giving you the same sequence of numbers.

---

Anyway, you can very well use `Alist.Count` in a call to a method, but you can't assign a number to it. You would have to add items to the list to change the `Count` property:

```
List<int> Alist = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
int index = RandomNumber(0, Alist.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, this should do the trick. this will take your list and sort it in random order:

list = list.OrderBy( itm => Guid.NewGuid() ).ToList();

Comment: May as well use `list.Sort()` instead.